# Problems with ping packet size

Tags: zsh, ping

I have some problems with pinging hosts with big packet size.

I'm doing some research on latency between one configuration and another.

I have written bash/zsh script to make it simpler that pings 8.8.8.8 and then parses the output to get average ping value. Script below:

```
#!/bin/zsh
for SIZE in {100..65500..100}
do
    ping 8.8.8.8 -c 5 -s $SIZE > tempfile
    TEMP=$(cat tempfile | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d / -f 2)
    echo "$SIZE - $TEMP" | tee -a results
done
rm tempfile
```

The problem is that with big packets (more than 30kB when the standard value is 64b) ping just doesn't work, I don't get any response just like the server was unavailable. Interestingly, when I was in another location, everything worked fine (Internet connection is a bit worse there), problems there started about 60kB but here they start about 30kB and to get one (out of ~300 to the end and bigger=worse) result I need to call this script ~10-20 times. It's really annoying because for smaller packets it's working like a charm (with the same server 8.8.8.8).

Anybody has an idea what causes it?

Comment: !!! cross-posting https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/485331/ping-big-packet-size-problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is related with IP Fragmentation, when you packet size is bigger that your maximum transmission unit (MTU) takes more that one packet and become pretty inefficient, take a look in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_fragmentation